# How to update a method that can be used for two different objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have an Object named Orders. In this object, I have two parameters Vehicle and Customer.
Right now I have a method called showOrder. This method will print the type of vehicle and the customer's name.

```
    public void showOrder() {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------|Order Placed|-------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("The order for the car type " + vehicle.getType() + " it was place on the name " + customer.getName() + " in date of " + date);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Let's say that in the future, I will add in the object Order a new Building property. How can I change this method now so that in the future, when I will add the new property, it will be possible to use it to display both Buildings and Vehicle types? Both of them will implement the Rentable interface.
The idea is that I want to make this code as generic and independent as I can...

I hope I was clear enough.
Thank you,

Comment: What does your `Rentable` interface look like? What does the rest of your `Orders` class look like?

Comment: If you have some orders that are vehicles, and others that are buildings, you can use polymorphism to define a superclass AbstractOrder and two subclasses VehicleOrder and BuildingOrder. The superclass can define and call abstract methods, such as showOrder(), or getDisplayName(). OTOH, if one order can have both a vehicle and a building, then you just need one class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to put an object of both the `Vehicle` type and the `Building` type into the variable `vehicle`. For that, you could use an abstract superclass that both the Vehicle and the Building class will inherit from. It may look something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract String getType();
}
```

The Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle extends AbstractClass {
    String type;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

The Building class then looks very similiar:

```
public class Building extends AbstractClass {
    String type;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Now, in the `Order` class, you need to change the type of the variable `vehicle` to `AbstractClass`. With that, you can put an object of both the `Vehicle` class and the `Building` class into that variable. The code in your `showOrder` method basically stays the same as both classes you could put into the `vehicle` object have the method `getType`.